# Samsung S3 - 40mb free ram of 1.5 gigs?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

My S3 has been lagging while I play in games or use aps. I've read that free ram is not supposed to be linked with lag but it seems that it must be. While in one of the games I play, my keyboard will not load, or will close randomly. I assume this is due to lack of ram to open it.

I have very few aps and almost no background processes. How is 1.44 gigs of my 1.5gigs of my ram being consumed?

Answer (score 0):

on the Play Store there are several utilities to clean Phone and speed up processes. My favourite is this:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard

Your excessive use of system RAM is (maybe) due to some persistently active process on your phone. Follow this guide to see yours (and maybe evaulate a uninstallation of some):
http://www.wikihow.com/See-What-Apps-Are-Currently-Running-on-Android

By the way, can you please tell us more information about your Android version?

Best regards,

Luca